# jquery calculate total amount of bill

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I have 3 text fields in my form. 1st one takes value of quantity in the bill 2nd one takes value of price of per unit item and 3rd one takes the value of applicable taxes. I am displaying the final bill amount in the 4th text field. I've tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Quantity, #Rate, #TaxAmount').keyup(function () {

        var total = 0.0;
        var qty = $('#Quantity').val();

        var rate = $('#Rate').val();

        var tax = ('#TaxAmount').val();

        var amount = (qty * rate);
        total = tax + amount;


        $('#TotalAmount').val(total);
    });
});
```

after running the code nothing is being displayed in the 4th textbox with id of `TotalAmount`. Unable to figure out what is the problem. Somebody please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you were missing `$` in the `var tax` line.

That aside, you'll need to use `parseFloat` to convert the strings you get from `.val()` to numbers, to be able to do arithmetic on them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $fields = $('#Quantity, #Rate, #TaxAmount');
  $fields.keyup(function() {
    var qty = parseFloat($('#Quantity').val());
    var rate = parseFloat($('#Rate').val());
    var tax = parseFloat($('#TaxAmount').val());
    var amount = (qty * rate);
    var total = total = tax + amount;
    $('#TotalAmount').val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity"> *
<input id="Rate" placeholder="Rate"> +
<input id="TaxAmount" placeholder="Tax"> =
<input id="TotalAmount" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$` sign before `('#TaxAmount')`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Quantity, #Rate, #TaxAmount').keyup(function () {

        var total = 0;
        var qty = $('#Quantity').val();

        var rate = $('#Rate').val();

        var tax = $('#TaxAmount').val(); // here

        var amount = (qty * rate);
        total = tax + amount;


        $('#TotalAmount').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.